# Can't start supervisor from yaws runmod

Tags: erlang, yaws

I have a yaws runmod defined in yaws.conf as:

```
runmod = sg_app
```

the module contains an exported function:

```
start()->
    io:format("~p start~n", [ sg_sup:start_link() ]).
```

When I start yaws I see a call to the runmod:

> =INFO REPORT==== 29-Oct-2015::16:46:51 === sync call sg_app:start
>
> {ok,<0.61.0>} start

But the supervisor is nonexistent:

```
1> whereis(sg_sup).
undefined
```

If I call the runmod:start manually, the supervisor hangs around.

```
2> sg_app:start(). 
{ok,<0.73.0>} start
ok
3> whereis(sg_sup).
<0.73.0>
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your runmod's `start/0` function is starting the supervisor with `start_link/0`, which means it's getting linked to the parent process. When that process dies, it takes your runmod process down with it, due to the link. The `runmod` feature isn't designed for starting a supervision tree.

You might instead consider using a [`yapp`](http://yaws.hyber.org/yapp_intro.yaws), which allows your code to run as a regular Erlang application in the same Erlang node as Yaws and be registered to have Yaws dispatch requests into it.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to launch your application using a separately spawned, infinite process:

```
start()->
    spawn(fun () ->
                  application:start(my_app, permanent),
                  receive after infinity -> ok end
          end).
```